# Powershell 6.2.3 unable to import AzureAd module

Tags: import, azure-active-directory, powershell-core

I am getting the below error when importing the "AzureAD" powershell module. I have installed the module, unable to import it. I have checked to see if there are any prerequisites required, nothing mentioned in GitHub.

Earlier, I was able to install and import "AZ" module.

**UPDATE : Resolved one dependency by copying the system.windows.forms.dll, but more runtime errors...**
[image]

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      6.2.3
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    6.2.3
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.17134
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

> VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\Program
>   Files\PowerShell\Modules\AzureAd\2.0.2.76\AzureAd.psd1'. VERBOSE:
>   Loading 'FormatsToProcess' from path 'C:\Program
>   Files\PowerShell\Modules\AzureAd\2.0.2.76\AzureAD.Format.ps1xml'.
>   VERBOSE: Populating RepositorySourceLocation property for module
>   AzureAd. VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\Program
>   Files\PowerShell\Modules\AzureAd\2.0.2.76\Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.dll'.
>   Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>   The system cannot find the file specified. At line:1 char:1
>   + Import-Module -Name AzureAd -Scope Global -Verbose
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

Comment: delete the azuread module completely with explorer and reinstall it?

Comment: Yes, have tried it..did not help. have also removed multiple copies of the azuread module and installed the latest 2.0.2.7 version.

Comment: I get the same error even with AzureADPreview module.

Answer (score 0):

Which .NET version are you using? You may need to update it as this was an issue with older versions. If that doesn't work you can remove the dependency on `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation` to get rid of the error in your screenshot.

Comment: .NET 4.6.1. Upgraded to 4.8, still no luck. How can remove the dependency on `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation` ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the AzureAD Module is not compatible with PowerShell Core due to the `WinForms` dependency. I have tried both `7.0.0` and `6.2.4` which did not work

However you can install it using the *Desktop* version of PowerShell. This version works for me.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.18362.752
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.18362.752
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Run elevated

```
Install-Module AzureAD
```

And then move on...

```
Import-Module -Name AzureAD

$creds = Get-Credential -Message "Credentials to connect to Azure AD"
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $creds

Get-AzureADCurrentSessionInfo
```